# How can I assign an Observable<Array[]> for function result that returns array of objects?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a function in a service that retrieves an array of objects with configurations. I'm trying to assign the return type to this method as Observable<GameInfo[]> but I'm getting the error:

```
Type 'Observable<object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<GameInfo[]>'.
   Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'GameInfo[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

I created interface for data validation that looks like this:

```
export default interface GameInfo {
  type: string;
  prizes: any;
  nameLocalKey: string;
  ticketPrice: number;
}
```

and tried to apply it, but it was unsuccessful.

It's my function that should return the Observable array:

```
  getGameList$(): Observable<GameInfo[]> {
    return this.httpService.get<GameInfo[]>(BackendRoutes.GameList);
  }
```

Data format:

```
[
    {
        "type": "BINGO_75",
        "prizes": [
            {
                "name": "Prize 1",
                "nameLocaleKey": "PRIZES.BINGO_75.PRIZE_1",
                "winAmount": 10,
                "patterns": [
                    {
                        "type": "HORIZONTAL",
                        "count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "VERTICAL",
                        "count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "DIAGONAL",
                        "count": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Prize 2",
                "nameLocaleKey": "PRIZES.BINGO_75.PRIZE_2",
                "winAmount": 10,
                "patterns": [
                    {
                        "type": "HORIZONTAL",
                        "count": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "VERTICAL",
                        "count": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "DIAGONAL",
                        "count": 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Prize 3",
                "nameLocaleKey": "PRIZES.BINGO_75.PRIZE_3",
                "winAmount": 10,
                "patterns": [
                    {
                        "type": "HORIZONTAL",
                        "count": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "VERTICAL",
                        "count": 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Prize 4",
                "nameLocaleKey": "PRIZES.BINGO_75.PRIZE_4",
                "winAmount": 10,
                "patterns": [
                    {
                        "type": "HORIZONTAL",
                        "count": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "VERTICAL",
                        "count": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Full house",
                "nameLocaleKey": "PRIZES.BINGO_75.PRIZE_5",
                "winAmount": 10,
                "patterns": [
                    {
                        "type": "HORIZONTAL",
                        "count": 5
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "nameLocaleKey": "GAMES.BINGO_75",
        "ticketPrice": 10
    }
]
```

**EDITED**

Here the code that send the data from server and we process this response inside function getGameList$()

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const gameList = require("../config/bingo");

router.get("/list", (req, res) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(gameList);

  const listOfGameConfigurations = keys.map((key) => {
    const currentGameConfiguration = gameList[key];

    const {
      type,
      prizes,
      nameLocaleKey,
      tickets: { price: ticketPrice },
    } = currentGameConfiguration;

    const newObject = { type, prizes, nameLocaleKey, ticketPrice };
    console.log(newObject);

    return newObject;
  });
  return res.json(listOfGameConfigurations);
});

module.exports = router;
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import BackendRoutes from 'src/app/core/enums/backend-routes';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/core/services/http.service';
import GameInfo from '../interfaces/game-info';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GameService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  getGameList$(): Observable<GameInfo[]> {
    return this.httpService.get(BackendRoutes.GameList);
  }
}
```

**EDITED 2**

Added httpService code:

```
export class HttpService {
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    withCredentials: true,
  };
  private domain = environment.domain;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  post(
    route: string,
    body: object,
    httpOptions: object = this.httpOptions
  ): Observable<object> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.domain}${route}`, body, {
      ...this.httpOptions,
      ...httpOptions,
    });
  }

  get(
    route: string,
    httpOptions: object = this.httpOptions
  ): Observable<object> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.domain}${route}`, {
      ...this.httpOptions,
      ...httpOptions,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code where the assignment happens including the declaration of the field you assign it to

Comment: Are you subscribing to your getGameList$ somewhere in your app?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm, I added two files

Comment: I mean the code, that calls `getGameList$`

Comment: @Mehyar Sawas I will subscribe in the app.component inside ngOnInit()

Comment: ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gameService.getGameList$().subscribe((el) => {
      console.log(typeof el); // object
      console.log(el); // [ {} ]
    });
  }

Comment: Can you post your main Http get call?

Comment: Please also post the definition of `HttpService.get`. In your first piece of code you call `httpService.get<GameInfo[]>(...)` as template but in the edit it's just `httpService.get(...)` (no template)

Comment: @Python29, I added httpService code

Comment: @churill, I added httpService code

Comment: Thanks for the update. No real surprise here `get` is declared as returning an `Observable<object>`, so what did you expect? Angular's `HttpClient` has a templated `get<T>(...)`. You should research about templates in typescript.

Comment: @churill, thank you, I'll try to rewrite this logic.

Comment: Good point churill. I recommend returning Observable<any> since you are creating a generic http service which does not always return the same response. Object is also not a generic type since the response could be object[]

Comment: And the cast the response type you are expecting in getGameList$() > this.https.get<GameInfo[]> since you are sure what you should get in the response

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help. The error was that I had a specific return type set. Generics helped.

```
export class HttpService {
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    withCredentials: true,
  };
  private domain = environment.domain;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  post<T>(
    route: string,
    body: object,
    httpOptions: object = this.httpOptions
  ): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(`${this.domain}${route}`, body, {
      ...this.httpOptions,
      ...httpOptions,
    });
  }

  get<T>(route: string, httpOptions: object = this.httpOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(`${this.domain}${route}`, {
      ...this.httpOptions,
      ...httpOptions,
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes to your HttpService. It should return `Observable<GameInfo[]>` because your function `getGameList$()` is expecting `Observable<GameInfo[]>`.

```
export class HttpService {
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    withCredentials: true,
  };
  private domain = environment.domain;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  post(
    route: string,
    body: object,
    httpOptions: object = this.httpOptions
  ): Observable<object> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.domain}${route}`, body, {
      ...this.httpOptions,
      ...httpOptions,
    });
  }

  get(
    route: string,
    httpOptions: object = this.httpOptions
  ): Observable<GameInfo[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.domain}${route}`, {
      ...this.httpOptions,
      ...httpOptions,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you change and why? A good answer should explain mistakes and solutions and not just provide code to copy-paste.

Comment: I'm type casting the Observable to `GameInfo[]` which is returned from Http.get method, as `getGameList$` requires that type.

Comment: Then you should add this to the question. But that's exactly the same as in the original piece of code in the question. And it's not casting, you are calling a template method. Also this is a custom service, not angular's `HttpClient`.

Comment: You are right, But we don't know about his httpService. I added comment to main question about his `HttpClient`'s `get` method.

Comment: What about the other type of responses from the server? A get request should have a generic type. In your solution you are considering all the responses coming from any api as GameInfo[]